# Function first. and last. in SAS,is there a corresponding function in R?

Tags: r, function, sas

Derived baseline flag, which is defined as the last non null test value before detection value.
Here is SAS code,function first. and last. in SAS,is there a corresponding function in R?

```
data T001;
  set aa;
  if .<ady<=1 and ^missing(avalc) then flag=1;
run;
Proc sort data=T001;by usubjid paramn flag egdtc visitnum;run;
data T002;
  set T001;
  by usubjid paramn flag egdtc visitnum;
  if last.flag and flag=1 then ablfl="Y";
run;
```

I also found some information, and I'm not sure if it's consistent
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-November/260997.html

Sorry, the data is like this. I inserted the picture, but I can't access it. I'm not sure whether the upload failed or the reason of the network firewall, so I copied the text directly , it looks messy and may need to be copied to excel and split.

exstdtc is drug exposure date

ady=egdtc-exstdtc (if ady>=0 need +1 ,i.e. if egdtc=exstdtc, ady=1)

ablfl is baseline flag.

[image: data image]

studyid usubjid param   paramn  avalc   egdtc   visitnum    exstdtc ady ablfl

A   A-S001  HR  1   10  2022/4/1    -1  2022/4/2    -1  Y

A   A-S001  HR  1   11  2022/4/3    1   2022/4/2    2

A   A-S001  HR  1   12  2022/4/6    2   2022/4/2    5

A   A-S001  RESP    2   20  2022/3/31   -1  2022/4/2    -2

A   A-S001  RESP    2   21  2022/4/1    1   2022/4/2    -1  Y

A   A-S001  RESP    2   22  2022/4/3    2   2022/4/2    2

A   A-S003  HR  1   11  2022/4/1    -1  2022/4/3    -2  Y

A   A-S003  HR  1       2022/4/2    1   2022/4/3    -1

A   A-S003  HR  1   12  2022/4/6    2   2022/4/3    4

A   A-S003  RESP    2   21  2022/3/31   -1  2022/4/3    -3  Y

A   A-S003  RESP    2   12  2022/4/4    1   2022/4/3    2

A   A-S003  RESP    2   22  2022/4/6    2   2022/4/3    4

A   A-S003  RESP    2   12  2022/4/8    3   2022/4/3    6

A   A-S003  PLUS    3   44  2022/4/1    -1  2022/4/3    -2  Y

A   A-S003  PLUS    3   44  2022/4/4    1   2022/4/3    2

A   A-S003  PLUS    3   44  2022/4/6    2   2022/4/3    4

Comment: Could you post an example of your data T001 and your desired output? Thanks.

Comment: With dplyr you could use `row_number`, something like `cumsum(!is.na(avalc))` and window function to achieve this I think. Without a sample of your data it's not easy to show you, as you are doing depending on a group of columns.

Comment: (first and last are not functions)

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but you can use lag() to check if the ID has changed and simulate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worte this code, it looks similar to the meaning of this code, compared with SAS code

```
adeg <- aa %>%
  mutate(FLAG = ifelse(ADY <= 1 & ADY>. & AVALC != "" , 1, NA)) %>% 
  arrange(STUDYID, USUBJID, PARAMCD, FLAG, EGDTC) %>% 
  group_by(USUBJID, USUBJID, PARAMCD, FLAG) %>%
  mutate(ABLFL = ifelse(row_number() == max( row_number()) & FLAG == 1,"Y",NA))
```

Comment: Is this an answer to your question or did you want to add something?

Comment: yes, this should be the result I want